# FindPackage(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED) does not find GTestConfig.cmake even though it exists

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am using vcpkg for dependencies in my project and getting the following error with CMake

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GTest" with any of
  the following names:

    GTestConfig.cmake
    gtest-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "GTest" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "GTest_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "GTest"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I followed these steps to get GTest with vcpkg:

1. clone vcpkg into root
2. `cd vcpkg` and run `./vcpkg bootstrap install`
3. `./vcpkg.exe integrate install`
4. `./vcpkg.exe install --x-install-root="build"`

and I got the following message

```
Total install time: 84.8 ms
The package gtest is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

    enable_testing()

    find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main GTest::gmock GTest::gmock_main)

    add_test(AllTestsInMain main)
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Blink LANGUAGES C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

enable_testing()

set(GTest_DIR "/vcpkg/build/x64-windows/share/gtest/")

find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(sing src/singing-card.cpp inc/singing-card.hpp inc/notes.hpp)
target_include_directories(sing PUBLIC inc)
target_link_libraries(sing PUBLIC ArduinoCore PRIVATE GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main GTest::gmock GTest::gmock_main)
```

I added the line `set(GTest_DIR "/vcpkg/build/x64-windows/share/gtest/")` based on the suggestion of the error message as `GTestConfig.cmake` is located under `root\vcpkg\build\x64-windows\share\gtest`. However, I still get the same error message.

What am I doing wrong such that `find_package()` is unable to find the config file even when explicitly providing a `GTest_DIR`?

**update**:

I changed `set(GTest_DIR "/vcpkg/build/x64-windows/share/gtest/")` to ``set(GTest_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vcpkg/build/x64-windows/share/gtest/")` and it appears now that CMake finds the file but gives this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "GTest" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    .../vcpkg/build/x64-windows/share/gtest/GTestConfig.cmake, version: 1.14.0 (64bit)
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Have you set the toolchain file?

Comment: @local-ninja I'm building from the command line using `cmake -G 'Ninja' -S. -Bbuild` with some other project specific arguments passed. By toolchain file are you refering to the file located at '/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake'? Apologies, I'm fairly new to CMake.

Comment: Follow these steps, the integrate command is only useful when working with visual studio (and vscode I guess). You have to set the toolchain manually otherwise: https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html

Comment: After following the steps in the link you provided I'm still getting the same error. The full command I am running is `cmake -G 'Ninja' -S. -Bbuild -D ARDUINO_PORT=COM4 -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=cmake/toolchain/promini.toolchain.cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
` I'm thinking maybe the issue is with specifiying two of DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE - although if I remove the first, the same error is still present.

Comment: Using your own toolchain file make things more complicated. I've never done that, but it's possible. Before going ahead, make sure to delete you CMakeCache.txt in your build folder, and remove `GTest_Dir` from your CMakeLists.txt. The following link describes how to use a custom toolchain in addition to the vcpkg toolchain: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration

Comment: It also doesn't seem like you're setting the toolchain file correctly. You have to provide the full absolute path. Your snippet seems to be relative.

Comment: Had some luck by adding `include(include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake))` to my custom toolchain `promini.toolchain.cmake` file and then running `cmake -S. -Bbuild -D ARDUINO_PORT=COM4 -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=cmake/toolchain/promini.toolchain.cmake`. That gets rid of the error complaining about not being able to find GTestConfig.cmake but i'm now getting "-- Running vcpkg install
error: Invalid triplet: x64-"

Comment: @Blargian: Please, edit your **question post** and make it to describe your **current problem**. Do not just append new "update" section to the post. Instead, rewrite the post so it will be devoted to the **single problem**, and it won't contain information not relevant to that problem. E.g. the error message `Could not find a package configuration file ...` is definitly not related to the error `vcpkg install error: Invalid triplet: x64`.

Comment: @local-ninja: "You have to provide the full absolute path. Your snippet seems to be relative." - CMake is able to automatically convert relative paths, specified in the command line via `-D` option, to absolute. CMake does that for every parameter of type PATH or FILEPATH. So, specifying a relative path in the `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<...>` is not a problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, I believe I solved this issue now after reading more into how to work with custom toolchains. I have posted a new question for a different issue I am having now at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77696885/vcpkg-and-gtest-integration-with-a-custom-toolchain-config-files-were-consider

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GTest" with any of
  the following names:

    GTestConfig.cmake
    gtest-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "GTest" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "GTest_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "GTest"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Occurs because I was not providing the vcpkg toolchain file to cmake anyhow. Without this file `find_package()` will not know the correct place to look.

It can be provided via command-line argument as `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path to vcpkg.cmake>`