# Vcpkg and GTest integration with a custom toolchain - config files were considered but not accepted

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, vcpkg

In my project I am making use of some template code which uses a custom cmake toolchain in order to [compile and upload code to an Arduino without using the IDE](https://github.com/tttapa/Arduino-AVR-CMake). As such there is a custom toolchain file called `promini.toolchain` located relative to my root directory at `cmake/toolchain/`. I am now trying to expand on the code from the repository linked above and integrate Google Test into the project using vcpkg.

I followed these steps to grab GTest with vcpkg:

- create the following `vcpkg.json` file in root:

```
{
  "name": "singing-card",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "gtest"
  ]
}
```

- clone vcpkg into root
- `cd vcpkg` and run `.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
- `./vcpkg.exe integrate install`

In my custom toolchain file `promini.toolchain` I have the following:

```
# variables related to custom toolchain
set(ARDUINO_BOARD "PRO")
set(ARDUINO_MCU "atmega328p")
set(ARDUINO_F_CPU "16000000L")
set(ARDUINO_VARIANT "eightanaloginputs")
set(ARDUINO_AVRDUDE_PROTOCOL "arduino")
set(ARDUINO_AVRDUDE_SPEED "57600")
set(ARDUINO_USB On)
set(ARDUINO_USB_VID "0x2341")
set(ARDUINO_USB_PID "0x8037")

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/avr.toolchain.cmake)

# chain on vcpkg toolchain 
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET x64-windows)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
```

When I run from my root directory `cmake -G Ninja -S. -Bbuild -D ARDUINO_PORT=COM4 -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=cmake/toolchain/promini.toolchain.cmake` I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:859 (_find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "GTest" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/Users/shaun/OneDrive/Desktop/singing-card/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/gtest/GTestConfig.cmake, version: 1.14.0 (64bit)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

From what I could see on the internet this is an issue related to the target triplet versions although I do not currently know enough about triplets, vcpkg, or even cmake, to know exactly how to solve this error.

Comment: The mark `(64bit)` after non-accepted configuration file means that given file describes the package for 64-bit platform, but you are building the project for 32-bit platform. Note, that you should choose vcpkg triplet not according to the host platform (where you are building the project), but according to the **target platform** (for which you are building the project). The target plaform is selected by a toolchain file. While I am not expect in Adruino, I don't think given platform is related to "windows", which you use as a triplet.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/8699#issuecomment-545098064) they suggest that you need to provide your own, custom triplet, which targets ARM.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is it not possible to separate out concerns between the Arduino related toolchain file and vcpkg one somehow, perhaps by having a separate target for GTest? After all I don't need GTest to compile for the Arm platform at all, rather just to compile for windows and test some C++ functions which will be compiled to the Arduino platform. Arduino libraries get included without vcpkg as they are present on my system already.

Comment: "just to compile for windows and test some C++ functions which will be compiled to the Arduino platform." - Assuming Arduino is ARM platform, so "some C++ functions" are compiled for ARM, how do you expect to test those functions on your Windows host, which is unlikely an ARM?

Comment: I don't quite understand your other question in the comment, but a single CMake project is build for a **single platform**. If you want different targets to be build for different platforms, then create separate CMake projects instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Understood, I see now why what I was saying makes no sense. I'll look into the custom triplet.